# What is wrong with the sentence: Scientists found some tracks in the area. It may be dinosaurs

Tags: meaning, sentence

I am solving some English tests and came up with question to identify the incorrect part in this sentence:

```
Scientists found some tracks in the area. It may be dinosaurs
```

But i didn't know what it is ???

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need a period after "dinosaurs".

Comment: Personally I would say *They may be those of dinosaurs*. Or you could say *It could be a case of dinosaurs*. But the way it stands at the moment is not strictly grammatically correct.

Comment: To someone of an anal nature the second sentence should be "They may be from dinosaurs" or some such.  "Tracks" is plural, so "It" should change to "They", plus the tracks themselves are not dinosaurs, but rather they are "from" dinosaurs or were "left by" dinosaurs or some such.  (Plus, of course, you need a period.)  But the sentence as it stands is perfectly fine idiomatic English, since one would assume that "It" refers to "the finding" or some such, and would assume that "be dinosaurs" would be interpreted as "signs of dinosaurs".  This is normal "short cut" English.

Comment: As an exercise, the test maker probably wanted you to spot the discrepancy between *It* (singular) and the possible antecedent *tracks* (plural).  Or perhaps it's the fact that dinosaurs are different from their tracks, arguing for the use of the possessive. Or both: *They may be dinosaurs'*  But as HH points out, *it* to refer to a general situation is perfectly idiomatic, so there's nothing really wrong grammatically.  As it stands, though, the sentence makes it sound like there's a  herd of dinosaurs leaving tracks in your area.  I hate it when that happens.

Comment: What @WS2 said. (And there are two sentences, as soon as the missing period is added.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two sentences are closely linked, as yours are, a semi colon should be used to separate them. 
As well as this, you state that 'some' tracks have been found and therefore the second sentence should continue the plural. I personally would say

'Scientists found some tracks in the area; they may be from dinosaurs.